# Outputs: functions vs. functions assigned to variables

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment, function-calls

I thought I had a decent understanding of how functions work and how they can be assigned to variables. However, I was just looking over some Learn Python the Hard Way exercises I read a few months ago (most notably exercise 21) and noticed some interesting things about the interpreter's output.

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b
```

Outputs:

```
>>> add(30, 5)
ADDING 30 + 5
35
```

Why does this show 35? Shouldn't you have to write "print add(30, 5)" for the return value to show up?

```
>>> age = add(30, 5)
ADDING 30 + 5

>>> age
35
```

The variable assignment looks like it calls the function and outputs the print statement and not the return value... but the variable itself shows the value 35, why doesn't the variable assignment do the same?

I hope these questions make sense. I'm just trying to get a better idea of what's going on behind the scenes. If anyone has any outside reading, let me know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the interactive interpreter displays the return value of any expression you type.

The function you posted has two lines. In the first line, it `print()`s the value to the standard output. The second `return`s the same value out of the function. As I stated above, this also gets written to the standard output in the *interactive* interpreter.

If you were to run your script via the command line (i.e. *not* in the interactive interpreter:

```
python myscript.py
```

You would notice that this return value is no longer printed to the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing that at the interactive Python prompt which, for your convenience, always prints the last result without you asking for it to do so. Otherwise, you'd have to be typing `print` all the time, which would get old quickly.

In a proper script, Python doesn't do that.

Comment: Saying the it "prints the last result" is a little misleading, as the interpreter will output the return values of _all_ expressions that don't evaluate to `None`, not just the last one typed. For example: `>>> for i in range(10):\n...    i + 10\n...    i + 5\n`.

Answer (score 0):

**add** both prints  see: `print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)`
and returns the integer (**only the integer**) see: `return a + b`

It always prints "**ADDING x + y**", want it or not.

If you assign the function to a variable, lets cal it **var**, then **var** will have the integer and nothing more (**which is what add returns**).